# SharePoint exception documentation

Tags: sharepoint, exception

I'm wondering where I can find some information about exceptions that are thrown by the SharePoint object model. Unfortunately regarding this, the documentation on MSDN is not very useful as the documentation of many methods is lacking information about what exceptions might be thrown and in which case they will be thrown.

So where do you get your information about exceptions from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly the best answer is it depends.  A lot of times I will start by doing a Google search of the error text.

If you are looking for a generic list of possible execptions thrown by SharePoint you will be very disappointed.  There is nothing out there that I know of.

Over time you will recognize patterns that will help you.

For example one common exception I have seen is "FileNotFound".  This usally occurs if I ask SharePoint to open an SPWeb or a SPList that does not exist.